# Возможность добавить собственный комментарий через очередь проверки сообщений низкого качества

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок, комментарии

Предлагаю добавить возможность написать свой комментарий при проверке сообщений низкого качества как при проверке вопросов. Либо добавить вариант "Хотя в ответе есть код необходимо добавить пояснение для полноценного ответа".

Я бы при проверке дописал комментарий в ответу и хочу что бы проверка была засчитана.

Скрин с примером

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что бы вы написали к этому ответу?

Comment: Вы все-таки уточните, за что же вы собирались удалять этот ответ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin нет, удалять ответ я не собирался. А вот написать комментарий про детальные ответы с последующим  засчитыванием правки как сделанной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На скриншоте под ответом отчетливо видна кнопка «добавить комментарий». Вы можете воспользоваться ей, оставить комментарий к ответу, а потом проголосовать за удаление.

Comment: в принципе как вариант

Comment: Вы серьёзно предлагаете удалять подобные ответы?

Comment: @Discord конкретно этот- нет, ни в коем случае. Потому и спросил, а что же автор вопроса хотел написать в комментарии.

Comment: Удалять ответ я не предлагаю, а написать комментарий и засчитать проверку как? Допустим пишу комментарий вручную, а потом кнопку "Выглядит нормально"?

Comment: @korytoff да, именно так. это будет засчитано как проверка (причем "Выглядит нормально" от двух участников предотвращает удаление другими ревьюверами)

Answer (score 2):

Если в ответе только код, то он в худшем случае некачественный и заслуживает минуса, но его **не нужно удалять** ни в коем случае!

Если в списке причин для удаления нет вашей причины, обычно это повод задуматься, правильно ли вы удаляете. Пропускать добавление комментария следует в нескольких случаях:

- Вы добавили более детальный комментарий вручную и хотите избежать дублирования.
- Кто-то другой уже добавил нешаблонный комментарий (если комментарий шаблонный, выбор той же причины поставит плюсик комментарию).
- Сообщение старое, и пользователь уже неактивен, поэтому комментарий бесполезен.

Но если ответ просто не слишком детальный, при этом содержит честную попытку ответить (он даже не обязан быть правильным) и соответствует правилам, то его не нужно удалять. Если ответ не нравится — можно минусовать. Удаляя, вы **уничтожаете полезную информацию**. Даже с удалением ответов-ссылок нужно быть осторожно. Если это единственный ответ, то часто лучше исправить его.